# How to add array elements to an object dynamically?

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

> Both answers below worked correctly, but I can't mark both as correct answer. Thank you guys <3

I have a problem and I don't know how to solve it so let's go :D

The problem is that I'm creating an event for Google Calendar API, and I need to add some mails on the "attendees" section dynamically, but I don't know how, 'cause I'm working on a variable, not on some dynamic creation of an object.

I have the mails on a JS Array.

If someone has any idea pls leave comment or answer.

I'll leave here the API request example if you need it for testing purposes: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=es#p/calendar/v3/calendar.events.insert

And sorry about my english, hope you understand me xD

```
console.log(invitados)                                  //Array con mails de los invitados
    //EVENTO PARA GCALENDAR
    var event = {
        'summary': titulo,                                      //Titulo evento
        'location': titulo,                                     //Ubicación evento
        'description': descripcion,                             //Descripcion evento
        'start': {                                              //Fecha ini
            'dateTime': fechaini,
            "timeZone": "Europe/Madrid"
        },
        'end': {                                                //Fecha fin (es igual a la fechaini con la hora de finalizacion)
            'dateTime': fechafinev,
            "timeZone": "Europe/Madrid"
        },
        'recurrence': [
            'RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL='+until+';'+byday          //Frecuencia de repeticion, hasta cuando, y que dias
        ],
        /*"attendees": [
            {
                "email": "mail@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                "email": "mail@gmail.com"
            }
        ],*/
        'reminders': {
            'useDefault': false,
            'overrides': [
                {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
                {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 24 * 60}
            ]
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following snippet to add an object array and push elements to it

```
event.attendees=[];
member={};
for(i=0; i<invitados.length; i++){
    member.email=invitados[i];
    event.attendees.push(member);
}
```

Comment: What's with the down vote? it works perfectly. Please accept the solution you are satisfied with.

Comment: i didn't downvote, I upvoted your answer! and I won't accept the solution 'cause I used the solution above, but thx for the help :)

Comment: I tried your answer and also works, but I can't accept both, idk what to do xD

Comment: Haha btw I have a lower reputation, please help a fellow user :P! Have a great day @IXTRUnai

Comment: Ok, ill give you the privilege of the accepted answer xD

Comment: Hi5 Bro! Try using JSFiddle, it helps in sharing and requesting questions to be solved regarding Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) :

```js
var invitados = ['mail@mail.com', 'mail@mail.com', 'mail@mail.com'];

var event = {
  'summary': 'summary',
  // ...
  "attendees": invitados.map((e) => {
    return {email: e};
  }),
  'reminders': {
    'useDefault': false,
    'overrides': [{
        'method': 'email',
        'minutes': 24 * 60
      },
      {
        'method': 'popup',
        'minutes': 24 * 60
      }
    ]
  }
};

console.log(event);
```